# textbox Control in GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, textbox

I've dropdown to language based on language selection change master page.

Where as I've gridview , this will bind with data based on language .

When i change language textbox value in gridview is not changing other than that remaining control values are changing .

Here is my Code of gridview

```
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:AFRResources, Status %>" ItemStyle-CssClass="gridLanguage-status"
                        SortExpression="STATUS" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblActive" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVE") %>'></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridLanguage-status" ForeColor="White" />
                        <ItemStyle CssClass="gridLanguage-status" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="<%$ Resources:AFRResources, SeqNo %>" HeaderStyle-CssClass="gridViolation-status"
                        ItemStyle-CssClass="gridViolation-status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                        HeaderStyle-ForeColor="White" SortExpression="STATUS">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="lblSeqno" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("SEQUENCENO") %>'></asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSeqNo" runat="server" Width="40%" Text='<%# Bind("SEQUENCENO") %>'
                                onchange="SetValue()" MaxLength="4" ></asp:TextBox>

                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Are you using `selectedValue/Text` of the dropdown to filter the data?

Comment: im using selected value other than textboxx remaining controls were bind correctly only the text box is not binding

Answer (score 0):

but you have to refresh your gridview i mean you could have a method that receives as parameter the selection from your dropdownlist you could maybe use the event SelectedIndexChanged

Comment: I think the SelectedIndexChanged would work perfectly as suggested. This is what I use on my gridviews. Make sure that the AutoPostBack="true" is enabled.